# MapView control in ESRI

Tags: c#, xaml, esri

I want to create Mapview control in xaml  as below but I get an error "The name Mapview does not exist in namespace http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/client/2009"

```
    <esri:MapView x:Name="MyMapView">
        <esri:Map Background="White" Name="mainDisplay" WrapAround="True" IsLogoVisible="False" 
              UseAcceleratedDisplay="False">
...
...
        </esri:Map>
    </esri:MapView>
```

The only reason to add Mapview is to know where the user has clicked on the map by its MapViewTapped MapViewInputEventArgs.location. I wonder if there is any other way to achieve this without using MapView? Please help

Comment: how could you know where someone clicked on a map without a map for them to click on?

Comment: If I remove the MapView control from xaml and just use 'map' the map is rendered fine. But when I add MapView I get an error which I want to correct